# hacer buscador con Django y JQuery

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, datatables

estoy intentanto crear un buscador de productos mi modelo es este

```
class Producto(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
precio_neto = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
promo_inicio = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
promo_fin = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
```

y tengo una template de la siguiente forma
[image: codigo tabla]
lo siento pero no encontre la forma de poner el html asi que coloque la img.

bien al final de ese archivo genero este script, segun yo usando algo de jquery
[image: script]

en mi vista tengo la siguiente clase en el cual me retorna un json

```
class ProductoViewSet(ListView):
template_name = 'producto/index_admin.html'
model = Producto

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    query = request.GET['name']
    productos = Producto.objects.filter(nombre__contains=query)
    producto = serializers.serialize('json', productos, fields=('nombre', 'categoria'))
    print(producto)
    return HttpResponse(producto, content_type='application/json')
```

mi url.py es esta:

```
path('search/', ProductoViewSet.as_view(), name='search'),
```

el detalle es que si hace la busqueda a la base de datos y me devuelve exitosamente el json, pero no lo carga a la tabla si no que en un formato distinto, ver las imagenes para que entiendan mejor.

[image: img 1]

[image: img 2]

como puedo hacer que en ves de que se muestre el json en el navegador me lo actualice en la tabla que esta ya creada?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es utilizar tu vista de como una API puedes usar directamente la librería de `Django RestFramework` y puedes ahorrarte mucho trabajo. Si por en cambio quieres realizar filtrados de objetos y maquetarlos puedes instalar `django_filters` que son formularios dedicados a hacer búsquedas y se utilizan igual que los ModelForm.